# Can someone explain how this if statement is working?

Tags: python, algorithm

Can someone explain how the if statement is working or the meaning of the code in the following code?

I have two lists, A and B, and I need to see if there exists a pair of elements, one from A the other from B, such that swapping them will make the sum of both lists equal.

My method, O(n^2) is to find the `sumOfA` and `sumOfB`. 
Find the `halfdiff = (sumOfA - sumOfB)/2`
For each element in A, see if there's a B[i] so that `(A[j] - B[i]) = halfdiff`.

But the following code does it in O(n+m). And I don't understand the meaning of "if" statement (LINE 11) here. Does it guarantee that if it is true we have the required pair?

```
1  def fast_solution(A, B, m):
2    n = len(A)
3    sum_a = sum(A)
4    sum_b = sum(B)
5    d = sum_b - sum_a
6    if d % 2 == 1:
7      return False
8    d //= 2
9    count = counting(A, m)
10   for i in xrange(n):
11     if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
12       return True
13   return False
```

Comment: What exactly does `counting(A, m)` function do? What does it return?

Comment: What is `m`? You mention `O(n+m)` runtime, and `fast_solution` takes an argument `m`, but your problem statement only ever talks about lists `A` and `B`.  Also, you didn't state it explicitly, but is it understood that `A` and `B` have the same length, `n`?

Comment: By the way: In Python you can write `0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m` as `0 <= B[i] - d <= m`.

Comment: The repetition of `B[i] - d` can't serve any purpose but to confuse the reader - `valueNeededInA` would spoil the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find `i`, `j` such that `sum(A) - a[i] + b[j] = sum(B) - b[j] + a[i]`, or equivalently, `sum(A) - 2*a[i] = sum(B) - 2*b[j]`.

You can do this by calculating all possible results of the right-hand-side, and then searching through possible i values.

```
def exists_swap(A, B):
    sumA = sum(A)
    sumB = sum(B)
    bVals = set(sumB - 2 * bj for bj in B)
    return any(sumA - 2 * ai in bVals for ai in A)
```

The partial code in your question is doing a similar thing, except `d = (sum(B)-sum(A))/2` and `count` is `itertools.Counter(A)` (that is, it's a dict that maps any `x` to the number of times it appears in `A`). Then `count[B[i] - d] > 0` is equivalent to there being a `j` such that `B[i] - d = A[j]`, or `B[i] - A[j] = (sum(B) - sum(A))/2`.

It may be that instead of using sets or dicts, the value `m` is the maximum value allowed in `A` and `B`. Then `counting` could be defined like this:

```
def counting(xs, m):
    r = [0] * (m+1)
    for x in xs:
        r[x] += 1
    return r
```

This is a simple but inefficient way to represent a set of integers, but it makes sense of the missing parts of your question and explains the bounds checking `0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m` which is unnecessary if you use a set or dict, but necessary if `counting` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not `O(n+m)`. Linear estimation is just amortized because of hashmap `count` usage. This knowledge may help you to understand that your code is an obfuscated version of

```
bool solve(A,B) {
    sum_a = sum(A)
    sum_b = sum(B)
    sort(B)
    for(val in A)
        if( binary_search(B, val - (sum_b - sum_a)/2 ) )
            return true
    return false
}
```

As Paul pointed out, `0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m` is just a validation of `count` argument. BTW his solution is purely linear, well implemented and much simplier to understand.